# why do we need synchronous on iOS?

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, synchronous

In fact, the only difference between a synchronous and an asynchronous connection is that the runtime will create a thread for the asynchronous connection while it won't do such thing for a synchronous connection.

In this case, a synchronous runs in the current thread, why do we still need synchronous? What's the difference between synchronous and ordinary code?

Comment: By "synchronous" do you specifically mean dispatch_sync? Or just the concept of synchronous things in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

synchrnous calls stops your current action and returns when the call returned. with async calls you can continue (e.g building up your user interface) and read the result once it is available. async is usually more complex, so it depends on the task which is the prefered solution.

Comment: I mean synchronous is the same to the ordinary code, we don't need synchronous.

Comment: synchronous communication is the sophisticated word for "normal" comm. you use it when talking of both posibilities async vs sync. if async is totally out of scope (e.g adding two integers) then you will not emphasize the word synchronous,

Answer (score 0):

If an API exposes synchronous methods it is usually because thread handling can be done by the user, or at least there are advantages to doing so. Asynchronous connections are good to use on your main thread to avoid blocking the user interface, but if you *already are* on a background thread, spawning *yet another thread* for an operation you don't mind blocking is a waste of resources, since thread creation is not cheap. Also, asynchronous APIs require more developer effort into controlling the flow of your logic.

As AlexWien says, synchronous is the opposite of asynchronous code, and therefore is *ordinary code*.